# When I import my data view on SPSS from Excel why does my variable view change completely? My label and measure is completely different

Tags: excel, spss

Before and after importing my data:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I fix this problem? Please be as detailed as possible because this is my first time using SPSS.

I expected my long label to remain after importing my data from excel

Comment: Welcome to Stack-Overflow! We may be able to help with your question but first you have to make it much more clear, right now it's impossible to understand what the problem is. Please edit your post with a more detailed explanation, better sreenshots, clear labels for the screenshots etc'.